# Calling a method from action class in .JSP file that takes an Enum parameter in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, enums

I'm using the Struts 2 framework. I have an action class and a JSP page. The class has the following two methods:

```
public String foo(String s)
{
    return s + s;
}

public String bar(SomeEnumClass EnumType)
{
    switch(EnumType)
    {
         //Return a string depending on the type. 
    }
}
```

I can call the first method using this in my .JSP file:

```
<s:property value="%{foo('some string here')}"/>
```

and it will correctly return to my .JSP:

```
some string heresome string here
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to call the second method. How can I let Struts 2 know the "string" `EnumTypeA` should be typecasted to the corresponding `EnumType`?

```
<s:property value="%{bar('EnumTypeA')}"/>
```

Struts offers a lot of built-in type conversion, but string to `enum` doesn't appear to be one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access enum from JSP using following notation:

```
<s:property value="bar(@package.SomeEnumClass@EnumTypeA)"/>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Just for reference for future readers: Do you need to add this line to struts.xml or not? 
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>

Comment: For accessing enum you **don't** need to enable `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess`.